# Serve a file for a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am trying to serve a file manually for a specific URL.

When I user the res.sendFile function I get the following error in my logs.

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'sendFile'

Express version : 4.13.3
```

It seems that this function is not available to use. There is a section about serving static content in the documentation but how would you serve it?

Updated code:

```
express = require('express');
app = express();

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body
app.get('/hi', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('File sent!');
    }
  });
});

app.listen();
```

Error logs

```
I2015-09-22T07:08:37.766Z]v39 Ran custom endpoint with:
  Input: {"method":"GET","url":"/hi","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,sq;q=0.4","cache-control":"no-cache","host":"......parseapp.com","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36","version":..........."}}
  Result: Success
I2015-09-22T07:08:37.855Z]TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendFile'
    at app.js:13:7
    at callbacks (express_router.js:161:37)
    at param (express_router.js:135:11)
    at pass (express_router.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (express_router.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (express_router.js:33:10)
    at next (connect_proto.js:240:15)
    at urlencoded (connect_urlencoded.js:51:37)
    at connect_bodyParser.js:64:7
    at json (connect_json.js:53:37)
```

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: Version 4.13.3 (Updated the post)

Comment: Then you need to show us some code because `res.sendFile`  should be available since 4.8.

Comment: Added my code and error logs

Comment: Something does not look right with your response. I would add `var util = require('util');` at the top, then put this statement just before the `sendFile` command and show us the logs: 
`console.log(util.inspect(res, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));`.

Comment: Try to add __dirname inside sendFile function

Answer (score 0):

can you compare the code with

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
app = express();

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(bodyParser.json());    // Middleware for reading request body
app.get('/hi', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('File sent!');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3100);
```

Comment: Tried the code. I ran into the following errors. 

I was unable to include body-parser. I tried installing the package but I don't think parse supports it.  And

__dirname was not defined so once removing that, I get the same error, sendFile is not defined.

Comment: it works perfectly, can you share your package.json. Not sure why you are unable to include body-parser, if your express is 4.*.* then you have to add body parser as express has removed the default body parser.

Comment: I found this thread from parse, it seems that this is a known issue;
https://parse.com/questions/is-there-an-alternative-to-expresss-ressendfile